# jQuery text() checking not working properly with Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following JSP/HTML code:

```
<dt>Birth Date:</dt>
<dd id="birth-date">-</dd>
```

However, when I use the following jQuery, the alert does not appear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#birth-date').text() === '-') {
        alert('Hello');
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what the problem could be, is it with Twitter Bootstrap because when I view the source, the browser shows this:

```
 <dd id="birth-date">


    -

 </dd>
```

And the above DOM is not exactly what I thought. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
if ($.trim($('#birth-date').text()) === '-') {
```

> The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including
>   non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the
>   supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of
>   the string, they are preserved, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Answer (score 0):

What about using a little regex magic?

```
if ($('#birth-date').text().replace(/\s+/g, '') === '-')
```

This should remove all whitespace from the `.text()` and compare that to the lone values of `-`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your JSP looks like this and doesn't contain any dynamic tags? Maybe something like this (pseudocode-ish):

```
<dd id="birth-date">
    ${ foo.getBirthDate() || '-' }
</dd>
```

Because in this case the HTML you see makes sense. Bootstrap itself cannot modify the HTML source though so it must be your server-side code.

---

Anyway, it's easy to fix with the current markup:

```
if ($('#birth-date').text().trim() == '-')
```

That way you remove all leading/trailing whitespace from the string and just get the `-` you are looking for.

Comment: Yep. I am 100% sure that the JSP tags are not being misunderstood here.

Comment: Well, bootstrap/javascript cannot modify the sourcecode shown in view-source. So if there is whitespace it's added on the server. Maybe something is "prettifying" your HTML?